# setMargins() won't work - Android

Tags: java, android, textview, android-relativelayout, margins

I've been looking for solutions for this problem for more than one hour now, but none is working. :/

I want to set the top margin of my TextView to a value depending on the integer position.
But somehow the margins won't show up...

```
public void addElements(int position, String title,int colour, RelativeLayout ld){
            int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    1, 
                    res.getDisplayMetrics()
            );

            int pos = 168*px;

            LayoutParams params;

            params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,144*px);
            params.setMargins(0, 168, 0, 0);

            TextView tv = new TextView(activity);
            tv.requestLayout();
            tv.setBackgroundResource(colour);
            tv.setText(title);
            tv.setSingleLine(false);
            ld.addView(tv, params);



        }
```

Comment: It doesn't work as in it doesn't display or everything works and the margin is off?

Comment: " it just won't work" please be more specific

Comment: the margin doesn't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 144);
    params.setMargins(0, 168, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

LayoutMargins are reserved for ViewGroup's such as RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc. Most common Views such as a TextView use padding in order to add additional spacing.

This should work:

`tv.setPaddingRelative(0,168,0,0);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it, but then it just added a normal padding... I'd like to use margin (as the TextView has a coloured background)